# I am trying to update model based on USER_ID but its using the ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

There is a form that is pulled correctly from the database and displayed. The problem is when I try to update the form, instead of updating where user_id = the user id, it's updating where user_id is equal to the rows ID.

```
Edit Function
@home = Home.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: current_user.id)


Form Page
<% if local_assigns[:profile_wizard] %>
  <% @path = wizard_path %>
  <% @is_remote = false %>
<% else %>
  <% @path = home_path %>
  <% @is_remote = true %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@home, :url => @path, :method => :put, :remote => @is_remote) do |form| %>


Home Update Func
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @home.update(home_params)
        format.js {render :js => "window.location.href='"+user_path(@home.user)+"'", notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.js {}
       end
    end
  end



User Model:
  has_one :home, dependent: :destroy

Home Model:
  belongs_to :user
```

Problem Now: I click update, this is what "params" puts to the console.

```
UPDATE "homes" SET "is_interested" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "homes"."id" = $3  [["is_interested", true], ["updated_at", "2019-09-05 14:12:27.352475"], ["id", 2]]
```

It should be where `homes.user_id = $3`

Comment: The home is found and loaded into the edit action using the user is, but the call to update uses that home object's id.  This is expected behavior.

Comment: @dbugger How would I pass in the current user id?

Comment: Why do you need to, you already have the proper object

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was in the update function

```
if current_user.home.update(home_params)
```

instead of

```
@home.update(home_params)
```